# Weak convergence of random variables implies $\mathbb E | X| \le \liminf_n \mathbb E|X_n|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Proof that, if $X_n \rightarrow X$ weakly, then $\mathbb E | X| \le  \liminf_n \mathbb E|X_n|$.

I know, that I should use Fatou's lemma but I don't know what can I do first.

Comment: The proof is indeed with Fatou's lemma, but not so easy. Here is a paper with it: http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4073v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$
Y_n = \sqrt{|X_n|}\\
Y = \sqrt{|X|}
$$
Then $Y_n\to Y$ weakly. Indeed:
$$
Ef(Y_n) = Ef(\sqrt{|X_n|}) \to Ef(\sqrt{|X|}) = Ef(Y)
$$because if $f$ is bounded continuous so is
$
x\to f(\sqrt{|x|})
$.

Then, consider a subsequence $X'_n$ such as $E|X'_n| \to \liminf E|X_n|$
$$
E(Y_n'^2) \to \liminf E|X_n|
\\
\begin{align}
0&\le E((Y_n' - Y)^2) = E(Y_n'^2) + E(Y^2)
- 2 E(Y_n' Y) \\&\to \liminf E|X_n| + E(Y^2) - 2E(YY) =  \liminf E|X_n| - E(Y^2) 
\end{align}
\\
\implies \liminf E|X_n| \ge E(Y^2)
$$